# Pulling MemberOf for members with matching data in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

I have been tasked with my first Powershell assignment of ultimately pulling the MemberOf groups for users with similiar job titles and departments based on their facility.  This is what I have so far.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$users = Get-ADUSER -LDAPFilter "(extensionattribute7=facility)"-properties department,title

$depts = $users | Select-Object Department -Unique
$titles = $users | Select-Object name,Title,Department -Unique | Export-Csv -NoType MyCSVfile1.csv
```

Now this works fine for me to pull the titles and departments unique to this facility. Now I need to somehow pull the group memberships associated with these job titles and their respective departments. This is ultimately to generalize group memberships and permissions for when new hires come in. I have tried a lot of different variations of code only to find myself face first on my keyboard silently sobbing.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you only want to know the groups shared by all users where they share the same department and title. Also have the output grouped as such?

Comment: Make a folder on your desktop named DefaultGroupProject. Add the `MemberOf` property to your `Get-ADUsers` call on line 3. Then run this: `$Users|Group Department,Title|ForEach{$DepTitle = $_.Name;$_.Group|Group MemberOf|Select Count,Name|Export-CSV "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\DefaultGroupProject\$DepTitle.csv" -notype}` You will have a CSV for each Department/Title grouping showing what groups those users belong to, and how many of each Department/Title set belong to each group listed.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Not confident that your comment is an answer?

Comment: Didn't take time to test it, but it _should_ work I think.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  I currently do not know what the shared groups are for these people.  Let me try to re-word it as my previous explanation was a little confusing.  I am trying to find the shared group memberships for employees who work in the same department with the same title, if that makes sense.  ex - two employees who work in marketing department with the same title of "marketing specialist".  I would need to find what group memberships they have in common.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$users = Get-ADUSER -LDAPFilter "(extensionattribute7=facility)"-properties department,title,memberof

$groups = $users | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf | Get-ADGroup -Properties name | Select-Object name -Unique
```

You can also filter the list of users based on jobtitle if you want or do a ldap filter on jobtitle instead and then get the unique groups for that job title.

Comment: This just looks likes `$groups` would be a list of all groups? There is no correlation between groups and position or counts.

Comment: well you would want to do this but instead of filter on facility filter on job title. then the list of groups would be the unique group memberships for each title. isnt that what you are looking for?

Comment: FYI I am not the OP. I just think you are missing an important part of what the OP is looking for.